# How to make a button inside Material-UI tooltip's title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, tooltip

I was able to pass Material-UI's IconButton inside Material-UI's Tooltip title.

All the views are working properly, except I cannot press the button.

I want to add a <kbd>Close</kbd> button to make the tooltip close on clicking the close button, but I cannot do that. Is there a way to do this? If yes, please provide a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

MUI's Tooltip has pointer-events set to none by default, so you need to enable this. Add a class to your tooltip and then add this to the css:

```
  pointer-events: auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone looking for this, here are some useful snippet for it.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Tooltip, Typography} from '@mui/material'
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close'


export const TooltipWithIcon = (title, message) => {
   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
   
   const handleClose = e => {
    if (open) {
      setOpen(false)
    }
    return null
  }

  return(
    <Tooltip
        open={open}
        title={
          <>
            <CloseIcon sx={{ float: 'right' }} onClick={e => handleClose(e)}></CloseIcon>
            <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ fontWeight: 700 }}>
              {title}
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant="body1" sx={{ fontSize: 14 }}>
              {message}
            </Typography>
          </>
        }
      >
      </Tooltip>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using Popper from Material-UI.